# Javascript in .js file, detecting presence of link in parent html

Tags: javascript

I am making some link bait which is basically an externally hosted .js file people can place on their websites. I would like an accompanying html link to accompany the widget however I would like the widget to detect if the link is present. i.e.

```
&lt;script src="http://domain.com/foo.js">&lt;/script><br />
by &lt;a href="http://domain.com">My Site&lt;/a> &lt;-- detect this is here
```

The issue is that i dont know on which sites my widget will be placed.

any ideas?

Comment: That link can easily be hidden using `display:none`. If you really want a "link bait", consider adding a small link near the active part of your code. If someone likes your feature, they might visit your site.

Answer (score 0):

```
var l = document.links, myLinkTest = false;
var linkcount = l.length;
while(linkcount > 0 && !myLinkTest) {
  if(l[linkcount-1].href == "http://domain.com"){myLinkTest = true;}
  linkcount --;
}
var widget = function(){
  if(myLinkTest){
    //do stuff
  }
}();
```

Test all links on page and only run script function if your link is found?

Comment: tried this and changed dostuff to document.write('it works'); but it doesnt report back success.

Answer (score 0):

You could look up all anchor elements and verify that an anchor with that href is there or verify with other criteria.

```
var isMyLinkPresent = function () {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        if(anchors[i].attr('href') === "http://domain.com") {
            return true;
        }
    };
    return false;
}
//in case you want to notify you own server of the presence, this will send a request to your server for picking up which site actually has the link
(function () {
    if (isMyLinkPresent()) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.attr('src', 'http://domain.com/tellmewhichsitehasit?site=' + window.location.host)
        document.head.appenChild(script);
    }
})();
```

Alternatively you could put the link yourself with javascript, but then you have to have some api the webmaster will use. Ex in the 'src' attribute of the script you can add parameters , you can then pick that up when generating the javascript or interpret it by looking at src.

Comment: hi ive tried this out, and removed the 'in case you want...' bits and changed return true; to document.write('works'); but its not reporting success... any tips?

Comment: can you provide an example of the HTML document you are executing it against?